# Python Mock imported library suds

Tags: python, mocking, patch, suds

I have a class that is using a suds client in several places to make some xml calls to another server.  No problems when the code is running, however, I cannot figure out how to mock the suds client creation in the class constructor such that it will create a mocked object and not use a real socket.  We have tried multiple permutations of `mock.patch`. `mocker.patch`, etc; but the ones that run result in a socket error and the rest result in *AttributeError* or *ImportError*.

This is a dumbed down version of the class:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.https import HttpAuthenticated

class MYClass(object):
    def __init__(self, host, usern, passw, provisioning_timeout=90):
        wsdl_url = 'https://{host}/server/GetWsdl?wsdl'.format(host=host)
        transport = CustomTransport()
        try:
            self.client = Client(wsdl_url, transport=transport, timeout=5)
    def run_wsdl(self, data):
        result = self.client.service.testwsdl(data=data)
        return result
```

And this is what I am trying to run through a unit test

```
from me import my_class
from mock import patch

#These are some of the many permutations we've tried
@patch('my_class.MYClass.suds.client.Client') #ImportError, no suds
@patch('my_class.Client') #Socket use error in __init__
@patch('my_class.suds.client.Client') #ImportError, no suds
def test_sip_stuff(mock_client):
    with patch.object(mock_client.client.service, 'testwsdl') as mockwsdl:
        mockwsdl.return_value = good_wsdl_data
        test_instance = my_class.MYClass(
            host='10.10.10.20',
            usern='user',
            passw='pass'
        )
        return_value = test_instance.run_wsdl(data='something')
        assert return_value == good_wsdl_data
```

Comment: 'my_class.Client' is correct and it sounds like it's correctly patching.

Comment: If its correctly patching, I would expect this line to not result in a socket being used: self.client = Client(wsdl_url, transport=transport, timeout=5)

Comment: Here is the beginning snippet from the stack trace using 'my_class.Client' as the patch.  It's clearly still using the real function and not a mocked version `me/my_class.py:27: in __init__
    self.client = Client(wsdl_url, transport=transport, timeout=5)
venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py:112: in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)`

Comment: You should use the fully qualified path, which would appear to be `@patch('me.my_class.Client')`